# HTML CSS: Grid Container Align Icons in Vertical Middle

Tags: html, css, svg, material-design

How do I align these items in the middle of the boxes? I tried everything vertical align middle, justify content, flex center, text align

Trying to avoid using div from answer suggestion below, unless required, is there another way?

```css
.material-icons
{
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle;
   border-color:black;
   border-width:1px;
   border-style:solid;

}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid-container" id="gridid1556351f5ece4ee3a7dce6962be48e39" style="  display: grid;
                    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 250px);
                    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 250px);
                    grid-gap: 1px;
                    padding: 0px;
                    align-items: stretch;
                    position: relative; ">
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i>
  <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this selector, `.grid-container i`, and use Flexbox to vertically and horizontally center the icon:

---

```css
.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 250px);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 250px);
    grid-gap: 1px;
    padding: 0px;
    align-items: stretch;
    position: relative; 
}


.grid-container i {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid-container" id="gridid1556351f5ece4ee3a7dce6962be48e39">
    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i>
    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i>
</div>
```

Comment: is this the most efficient way of doing it? why didnt my css properties work above? there must be another way    align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
   text-align:center;
   vertical-align: middle;

Comment: I updated my answer using @Soothran's solution.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work using grid I would wrap the `<i>` in a `<p>` element and the `<p>` gets `justify-self: center; align-self: center;`

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 250px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 250px);
  grid-gap: 1px;
  padding: 0px;
  position: relative;
}
p {
  justify-self: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.material-icons {
  border-color: black;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">

<div class="grid-container" id="gridid1556351f5ece4ee3a7dce6962be48e39">
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">notifications</i></p>
  <p><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:48px;">delete</i></p>
  
</div>
```

Comment: interesting, khan wants to do this,.grid-container i { ,  not sure which answer is better or even matters, thanks though !

Answer (score -2):

Make the class `.material-icons` to a flex-container by adding `display:flex` property. You might have to increase the css priority of this style to override the default display style of `.material-icons`

```
.grid-container > .material-icons{
display:flex;
}
```

Comment: this is not working, did you try it on codepen?    display:flex;

Comment: because material css is overriding your custom styles. So either you can put !important property (display: flex !important) or load your custom css file after loading material css

Comment: can you provide working example in code pen, etc? thanks

Comment: @Soothran is right, you can just put `display: flex`.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ydwBLb?editors=1100#anon-login check this

Comment: Its working at my end. Still don't understand why this became a useless answer. @Khan's modified answer does not requires !important. Its a nice approach